# Open Graph Object Debugger returns 404 on my wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I am the admin for a wordpress site and I am really stuck.

When people share a post via Facebook, it Facebook is not rendering a preview for the post. I therefore debugged the link to be shared via go debugger and it returns a 404 error.

This link is the link to be shared:
http://www.fridafridafrida.com/coverwow-i-d-magazine-fall-2014/

As you can see, it perfectly loads in the browser. But why is Facebook not able to access it?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an open graph plugin? Is your website already included with open graph properties? if yes, this could be a conflict between the two of them. In other case scenario try to re-write the url, add like a hifen between `cover-wow` and debug it again

Answer (score 0):

Prolem solved.

I found out that the page itself worked absolutely fine. The problem was resolving the IP via DNS. Facebooks uses ipv6 resolution and the address in my DNS was pointing to the wrong place.

Thanks,
rainer